# Display form inputs according to previous answers nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm actually trying to build a webapp and I am quite a beginner.

I am using nodejs and express for the backend and I don't know how to display some form inputs according to the answer I give in a previous input.

For exemple, if i check a checkbox, i would like to display an other form.

First I made my static page using classic html and js and I could have the result i needed by checking if the checkbox is checked and then change the style of the input from none to block.

For exemple,
In my html file :

```
<div class="form-check form-switch my-2 col-md-2">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="SwitchCheckLicence">
      <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="SwitchCheckLicence">Licence payed?</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 fw-bold" id="Paiement" style="display:none;">
      <label for="inputPaiement" >Prix : </label>
      <select class="form-select" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
      <option selected>Choisir un moyen de paiement</option>
      <option value="CB">Carte Bancaire</option>
      <option value="Cheque">Chèque</option>
      <option value="Espece">Espèce</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

And in my js file :

```
var licencePayed = document.getElementById('SwitchCheckLicence');
var Paiement_div = document.getElementById('Paiement');
var showHiddenDiv = function(){
    if(licencePayee.checked) {
    Paiement_div.style['display'] = 'block';
   }
licencePayee.onclick = showHiddenDiv;
showHiddenDiv()
```

But now that I am rendering the pages server side, is there a way to have the same result and to have a form that can adapt dynamically ?

Tell me if you need more precision, thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Veezia, how are you trying to render it server side? The server side render should render the first form, and the javascript should "hydrate" the form and add the reactivity

Comment: But there is nothing really dynamic in your html to even be rendered server side anyway

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Acidic9. Well, I'm using EJS to render my pages if it's what you want to know.
If I understand well, I should only render with EJS the first input and then add the others with the javascript ? But how can I know that the user is done with the first input without asking him to press a button or someting ?

Comment: Yes that sounds correct. You could include all the html, but just set the 2nd form to display none initially, and show it with JavaScript. And regarding your second question, you could try to do something smart, like when they blur the input with the blur event, but I think having a button is fine

Comment: Then it's pretty much the same as I made in my html.
But as I can't access the DOM, I can't change the display style with javascript

Comment: You still serve the JavaScript to the user. You cannot make dynamic things server side rendered like form control.